Problem when using python virtualenv: when creating a virtual env with python3 -m venv venvs/mon-env , the list of package is very long
It is not possible for me to create an empty virtual environment.
I can see the list of package despite the key include-system-site-packages = false
For information multiple versions of Python are installed:
Python 2.7
Python 3.7
Python 3.9
python --version
Python 2.7.16
python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
python ==> /usr/bin/python
python3 ===> /usr/bin/python3

Running python -m venv <dir> will create a clean venv directory. Querying for installed packages using venv will list all packages installed in the default site-packages directory. Can you provide the venv creation logs?

After some search, it seems that it is the $PYTHONPATH which contains the path to the ros package which includes these package.
So, I did:
unset PYTHONPATH
python3 -m venv venvs/mon-env
source venvs/mon-env/bin/activate
pip list
pip           18.1   
pkg-resources 0.0.0  
setuptools    40.8.0

It seems to work.
